# change text color on change of selection in dropdown list for each row

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a dropdown list of different colors on one row, and when list selected, i would like to change a value of text color on that row to the value of the selection. 
Each row have one field of dropdown list, everytime user select dropdown list all the field on that will change the same color.

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
     function updateTextColour(value) {
            if (dropdownList.value > 0) {
                dropdownList.style.color = 'red';
                //document.body.style.color = '#' + value;
        } }           
    </script>        
    <style type="text/css">.style1 {color: #FF0000;}</style
</head>
<body>
    <form>Change the text color: <br>
       <table>
       <tr>
    <td id="1" style="width:40px">1</td>
    <td id="1" style="width:180px" class="style7">
        <span class="style1"><span class="style1">           
        <select name="backGround" size="1" onChange="updateTextColour(this.value);"><!--changeColor(this.selected);"-->
            <option value="FF0400" style="color:red">[Red]</option>
            <option value="05EF00" style="color:Green">[Green]</option>
            <option value="0206FF" style="color:Blue">[Blue]</option>
            <option value="000000" selected>[black]</option>
        </select></span></span></td>
        <td "width:auto" class="style8">Need to change to color row 1</td>   
        <br><br></tr>
        <table> 
        <tr>
        <td id="2" style="width:40px">2</td>
        <td id="2" style="width:180px" class="style7">

        <span class="style1"><span class="style1">  
        <select name="backGround2" size="1" onChange="updateTextColour(this.value);"><!--changeColor(this.selected);"-->
            <option value="000000">[Black]</option>
            <option value="FF0400" style="color:red">[Red]</option>
            <option value="EFE800" style="color:Yellow">[Yellow]</option>
            <option value="05EF00" style="color:Green">[Green]</option>
            <option value="0206FF" style="color:Blue">[Blue]</option>
            <option value="FFFFFF" selected>[White]</option>
        </select></span></span> </td>
        <td "width:auto" class="style8">Need to change to color row 2</td>
        </tr>
        </table></table>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a change in the Javascript for this to work.

[**Working Solution**](http://jsfiddle.net/AG3dz/)

Use this Javascript

```
function updateTextColourrow1(value){        
     document.getElementsByClassName("style8")[0].style.color="#"+value;
} 
function updateTextColourrow2(value){
     document.getElementsByClassName("style8")[1].style.color="#"+value; 
}
```

I have used two functions to access the two rows separately. This can also be done using only one function.

***Era800's*** method.

***JS***

```
function updateTextColour(sender) {
    var tempie = sender; //the dropdown list object

    //Find the table row of the dropdown list.
    while (tempie.parentNode.nodeName != 'TR') {
        tempie = tempie.parentNode;
    }
    //Get the selected color.
    var selectedColor = '#' + sender.value;

    //Set the row to the selected color.
    tempie.parentNode.style.color = selectedColor;
}
```

There is a slight change that needs to be done in the script that era800 posted, you need to prefix '#' to the var selectedvalue.

**[Working Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/AG3dz/1/)**

Comment: Hi, Thanks so much for quick responded, I am new to this and did try out both code, but doesn't seem like it work. maybe I didn't do correctly. my tale will have alot of rows, each row have odropdown list field and dorpdown list have three selection, (1) red (2) cr

Comment: So the second solution will work just fine. How come they did not work. I tested the codes in all browsers

Answer (score 0):

Try passing `this` instead of `this.value` into `updateTextColour`.

Example: `onChange="updateTextColour(this);"`

And use this JavaScript function:

```
function updateTextColour(sender) {
    var tempie = sender; //the dropdown list object

    //Find the table row of the dropdown list.
    while (tempie.parentNode.nodeName != 'TR'){
        tempie = tempie.parentNode;
    }
    //Get the selected color.
    var selectedColor = sender.value;

    //Set the row to the selected color.
    tempie.parentNode.style.color = selectedColor;
}
```

Comment: not bad. Needs a slight alteration and will work. i shall update in a fiddle

Comment: You are the best, and it work very good. Just wonder the FF is work good but not in IE. any advice, thanks so much

Comment: Nevermind, It is work I need to turn on the active X..Thanks again for the help..very appreciated.